# Null Conditional Operator, not behaving as expected on some machines

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

I have the following code in a DelegatingHandler for a WebApi 2 project.

```
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var content = await request.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _log.Information("Received {request} with content body: {content}.", request, content);

        // Run the rest of the request pipeline.
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        var responseContent = await result.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _log.Information("Returning {result} with content body: {responseContent}.", result, responseContent);

        return result;
    }
```

On my machine this works as expected and during a response that is a 301 Redirect (where result.content would be null) I get responseContent == null; however, on a co-workers machine he receives a null reference exception on this line. We are both using the 4.5.1 runtime, the differences as far as we can tell is as follows follows:

- I'm using VS2015 Enterprise SP2 (where it works), he's using VS2015
  Professional SP2 (where it doesn't work)

Ninja Edit - [the .NET versions and service packs I have installed as well as the ones he has installed](https://gist.github.com/robbihun/5804072a144c8050c07cb01fb25bcd2c)...

It looks like the machine where it is not working has two 4.5.1 security updates installed ([KB2901126](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2901126) & [KB2931368](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2931368)) that I do not, would one of these cause this issue? Is there a difference in the compilers or compiler options that I need to check? Or am I looking into something that has a simpler explanation?

Comment: Have you tried with an old school null check?

Comment: The same binaries on different machines..or another compilation? Compare  the IL code if it is another compilation

Comment: If result.Content would be null, you will end up with "await null" which should throw NullReferenceException. You sure that in your case result.Content is really null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the difference between the two machines is, but your code is wrong:

```
await result.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

What this does, is that when `result.Content` is not `null`, `ReadAsStringAsync()` is called and its result is `await`ed, as it should. But when `result.Content` is `null`, the whole subexpression `result.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync()` is `null`, which means that the `await` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

So, if you want to protect against `result.Content` being `null`, you should probably use an old-fashioned `if` or a ternary operator.

Comment: Ah. you're right! Thanks for that... I still need to figure out why "await null" does not throw an exception on my machine, but does on my coworkers machine... or if i'm actually getting a content body on my machine for a 301 redirect... either way i still have a problem but this does answer this particular question.